# Drupal TB mega menu is so slow

Tags: navigation

I am developing a website using **Drupal** and **TB Mega Menu** for my main menu, when I used **Devel** to check the execution time I found that **TB Mega Menu** is taking about **23978.991 ms** on the following query;

> SELECT m.load_functions, m.to_arg_functions, m.access_callback,
>   m.access_arguments, m.page_callback, m.page_arguments,
>   m.delivery_callback, m.title, m.title_callback, m.title_arguments,
>   m.type, m.description, ml.* FROM menu_links ml LEFT JOIN menu_router m
>   ON m.path = ml.router_path WHERE ml.menu_name = :menu ORDER BY p1 ASC,
>   p2 ASC, p3 ASC, p4 ASC, p5 ASC, p6 ASC, p7 ASC, p8 ASC, p9 ASC

Any idea why ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad, is probably as bug report for the TB Mega Menu module, and has been [cross-posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671583/drupal-tb-mega-menu-is-so-slow)

Answer (score 1):

Could be you're missing a mysql index... The 9 "ORDER BY" clauses in the query would run really slowly without an index called "menu_parents".  To find out if you have it, run the following:

```
SHOW INDEX from menu_links
```

If everything is set up correctly then you should get something like:

```
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| menu_links |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | mlid         | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | path_menu              |            1 | link_path    | A         |        1286 |      128 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | path_menu              |            2 | menu_name    | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_plid_expand_child |            1 | menu_name    | A         |          67 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_plid_expand_child |            2 | plid         | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_plid_expand_child |            3 | expanded     | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_plid_expand_child |            4 | has_children | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            1 | menu_name    | A         |          61 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            2 | p1           | A         |         428 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            3 | p2           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            4 | p3           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            5 | p4           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            6 | p5           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            7 | p6           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            8 | p7           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |            9 | p8           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | menu_parents           |           10 | p9           | A         |        1286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| menu_links |          1 | router_path            |            1 | router_path  | A         |        1286 |      128 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

If you're missing the "menu_parents" rows then you can run the following:

```
CREATE INDEX menu_parents ON menu_links (`menu_name`,`p1`,`p2`,`p3`,`p4`,`p5`,`p6`,`p7`,`p8`,`p9`)
```

If that doesn't help then it might be worth posting the result of an EXPLAIN of your query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT m.load_functions, m.to_arg_functions, m.access_callback, m.access_arguments, m.page_callback, m.page_arguments, m.delivery_callback, m.title, m.title_callback, m.title_arguments, m.type, m.description, ml.* FROM menu_links ml LEFT JOIN menu_router m ON m.path = ml.router_path WHERE ml.menu_name = "main-menu" ORDER BY p1 ASC, p2 ASC, p3 ASC, p4 ASC, p5 ASC, p6 ASC, p7 ASC, p8 ASC, p9 ASC
```

(assuming that "main-menu" is the menu being queried).